# How to find the nearest integer point from a region to a specified point

Tags: regions

```
RegionNearest[Disk[{0, 0}, 10], {15, 3}]
RegionNearest[Disk[{0, 0}, 10], {0, 1.5}]
```

The [`RegionNearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionNearest.html) function can find the nearest point from a region to a specified point ,But the results it returned was  real numbers.

I want to find out the nearest integer coordinate of the region from point P.How can I do this?

Comment: Could use `Minimize` as: `In[10]:= Minimize[{(x - 15)^2 + (y - 3)^2, x^2 + y^2 <= 100, 
  Element[{x, y}, Integers]}, {x, y}]
Out[10]= {34, {x -> 10, y -> 0}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pnts = RegionIntersection[Disk[{0, 0}, 10], 
   Point[Tuples[Range[Ceiling @ #, Floor @ #2] & @@@ RegionBounds @ Disk[{0, 0}, 10]]]];

RegionNearest[pnts, {15, 3}]
```

> {10, 0}

```
RegionNearest[pnts, {0, 1.5}]
```

> {0, 2}

```
Row[Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point @ #, 
     Blue, Point @ RegionNearest[Disk[{0, 0}, 10], #], Black, 
     AbsolutePointSize[10], {Point @ #, Text[#, Offset[{10, 0}, #], Left]} &@
      RegionNearest[pnts, #], 
     Opacity[.5, Green], Disk[{0, 0}, 10]}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-15, 15}}] & /@ 
  {{15, 3}, -{15, 3}, {0, 1.5}},
 Spacer[1]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Nearest`:

```
nF = Nearest[Select[RegionMember[#]]@
      Tuples[Range[Ceiling@#, Floor@#2] & @@@ RegionBounds@#] & @ Disk[{0, 0}, 10]];

nF /@ {{15, 3}, {0, 1.5}}
```

> {{{10, 0}},
>   {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}}

Finally, you can use `Minimize`:

```
Quiet @ Minimize[{Norm[{p, q} - #], 
   Element[{p, q}, Disk[{0, 0}, 10]]}, 
 {p, q}, 
 Integers] & /@ {{15, 3}, {0, 1.5}}
```

> {{Sqrt[34], {p -> 10, q -> 0}},
>   {0.5, {p -> 0, q -> 1}}}